# MongoDB - How to get the documents based on two column values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My MongoDB collection  with sample data is attached with the screenshot below

[image]

I want to fetch rows by passing grade value and the resulting records should be returned as follows

- case 1: when grade = 12, Row 1,3,6 and 7 should be returned ie  given
  grade 12 should compare with gradeFrom and gradeTo
- case 2: when grade = 1, Row 5 should returned

As a summary of above cases, the given grade should be greater than or equal to gradeFrom  AND less than or equal to gradeTo.

The mongoose query that I used is given below, but the data returned is empty in my code

```js
let andCondition = []; 
let grade = 12;
andCondition.push({ gradeFrom: {$gte: grade}});
andCondition.push({ gradeTo: {$lte: grade}});
let data = await Course.find({$and :andCondition});

console.log(andCondition) gives the below object

[ 
    { gradeFrom: { '$gte': 12 } }, 
    { gradeTo: { '$lte': 12 } } 
]
```

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: Should be `gradeFrom: {$lte: grade}` and `gradeTo: {$gte: grade}`. Reversed logic. Math logic: gradeFrom <= grade <= gradeTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reversed the range logic.

In Math, it should be:

```
gradeFrom <= grade <= gradeTo
```

While in MongoDB query:

```
{ gradeFrom: { $lte: grade } }
{ gradeTo: { $gte: grade } }
```